# Drag & Drop Email - Document Library vs. Web part

Tags: sharepoint-online, web-part, document-library, outlook, modern-document-library

I'm experiencing two different drag & drop experiences when using the Document Library vs. Document Library Web Part in SharePoint Online when dragging an email from Outlook (Version 1902 Build 11328.20368 Click-to-Run).

**Document Library** - When dragging the email, the email is *copied* to the document library.

**Web Part** - When dragging the email, the email is *moved* from the Outlook inbox to the document library.

The preferred function is the first, where the email is copied. Is this expected behavior? Is this something I'm able to change?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It should not move, it should actually copy while doing the drag and drop.

I assume you are following the below steps, while doing the drag and drop, if not please verify it.

1. Go to the SharePoint library with the Internet Explorer browser.
2. Open the library with file explorer via Open with Explorer.
3. Drag the .msg file to the file explorer.
4. Refresh the library page to check if it is uploaded.

As per the below Microsoft thread it should copy while performing the drag and drop following the above steps :

[Drag and drop from Outlook inbox into Sharepoint document library](https://answers.microsoft.com/en-us/msoffice/forum/all/drag-and-drop-from-outlook-inbox-into-sharepoint/ea9e8256-9ef1-4853-b96e-6c3713d7d25f)

You may refer the below article for how three ways we can upload emails to SharePoint:

[3 out of the box ways to save emails in SharePoint](https://sharepointmaven.com/3-out-of-the-box-ways-to-save-emails-in-sharepoint/)

You may try the third-party tool **Harmon-ie** which works well for outlook and SharePoint file uploading.

Comment: It seems that your steps don't apply to modern document libraries.

Answer (score 0):

Per my test, when I drag the email to the document library, the email is copied to the document library. When I drag the email to the document library web part, the email is moved from the Outlook inbox to the document library. I think this behavior is by default.

Comment: Dang.. Thanks for your feedback!